# i want to insert <br /> tag in this map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am studying React JS, but I have some difficulties so I am writing a question.

Here is my code.

```js
const ServiceList = [{
    icon: '01',
    title: 'TEST',
    description: 'There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered.',
}, {
    icon: '02',
    title: 'TEST',
    description: 'There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered.',
}, {
    icon: '03',
    title: 'TEST',
    description: 'There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered.',
}, ]
```

```
{
  ServiceList.map((val , i) =>
    (                        
      <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12" key={i}>                           
        <p>{val.description}</p>
      </div>
    )
  )
}
```

In this code, I want to display val.description like this

```html
<p>
  There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available,
  <br />
  but the majority have suffered.
</p>
```

I've tried several methods (like `\r`, `\n`, etc..) so that the content of the description is a line break like the `<br />` tag, but it didn't work.

Please tell me another try options.

Very Thanks.

Comment: If you are using bootstrap, try to use the class `text-break`. [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/text/#text-wrapping-and-overflow) about it

Comment: i'm not using bootstrap, thanks for comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your array, and display a description as a tag. In this case, you can put `<br />` inside of the text.

Example

```
{
    icon: '03',
    title: 'TEST',
    description: <>{'There are many variations of'} <br /> {'passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered.'}</>,
}
```

Comment: wow you are genius! :), very thanks!!,

By the way, do you recommend this method?

Comment: This could be simplified to `description: <>There are many variations of <br /> passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered.</>,`

Comment: I would recommend you create a dump component to display the description.

for instance.
<StyledDescription text = 'example'> and use it in your array.

{
    icon: '03',
    title: 'TEST',
    description: <StyledDescription text = 'example'>
}

Comment: You should not mix state/data with rendering info. If you need to display the data with line breaks, let the rendering handle the transformation, See my [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65689614/1762224) below using an interleaving technique. If the data within `ServiceList` is coming from an external rest service, it must be valid JSON. You will still need to interleave it.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I will refer to it for studying. Thank you.

Comment: Wow, this works like magic, after searching for months for this. You're good

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but its not a good practice

```
render() {
    const description = 'There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, <br /> but the majority have suffered.'
    return <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {
      {
        __html: description
      }
    } > < /p>
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could interleave the `<br>` elements and return the resulting array to be rendered.

You want to split your description via: `/(?<=,) /g`. This will split on the space following the comma, but the comma will be kept. This is called a "positive lookbehind" regular expression.

```
const interleaveItems = (items, delimiterCallback) => {
  const result = [items.shift()];
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    result.push(delimiterCallback());
    result.push(items[i]);
  }
  return result;
};

const Description = ({ description }) => {
  return interleaveItems(description.split(/(?<=,) /g), () => <br />);
};
```

### Full example

```
import React from "react";

const styles = {
  root: {
    display: "grid",
    gridRowGap: "1em"
  }
};

const App = () => {
  const ServiceList = [
    {
      icon: "01",
      title: "TEST",
      description:
        "There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered."
    },
    {
      icon: "02",
      title: "TEST",
      description:
        "There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered."
    },
    {
      icon: "03",
      title: "TEST",
      description:
        "There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered."
    }
  ];

  const interleaveItems = (items, delimiterCallback) => {
    const result = [items.shift()];
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      result.push(delimiterCallback());
      result.push(items[i]);
    }
    return result;
  };

  const Description = ({ description }) => {
    return interleaveItems(description.split(/(?<=,) /g), () => <br />);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App" style={styles.root}>
      {ServiceList.map((val, i) => (
        <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12" key={i}>
          <Description {...val} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```